# Dot product of the gradient of a function

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

In matrix calculus, I keep on seeing things like $\langle \nabla f(x), v\rangle$, which is the dot product of the gradient of a function with a vector.

I was wondering if there is any intuitive understanding of what this means.

For example, we have the Mean Value Theorem:

> Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and suppose
>   the mapping $F : \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is
>   continuously differentiable. Suppose that the points $x$ and $x + h$
>   are in $\mathcal{O}$ and that the segment joining these points are
>   also in $\mathcal{O}$. Then, there exist numbers $\theta_1, \theta_2,
>  \ldots, \theta_m$ in the open interval $(0, 1)$ such that  $$F_{i}(x +
>  h) - F_{i}(x) = \langle \nabla F_{i}(x + \theta_{i}h), h\rangle $$

I was wondering if there is any good way to interpret $\langle \nabla F_{i}(x + \theta_{i}h), h\rangle$ in this context.

Thanks

Comment: It can be shown that $\langle \nabla f(x), v \rangle$ is equal to the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ in the direction $v$.

Comment: product of magnitudes times the cosine of the angle between v and f(x) "uphill"

Comment: Are you famiiliar with the multivariable chain rule $df=\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the derivative $d_pf$ of $f\colon\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ in a point $p$ is not a vector, but a linear form instead.

In presence of an inner product $\langle.,.\rangle$
the gradient $\nabla^{\langle .,.\rangle}f(p)$ in respect to the inner product $\langle .,.\rangle$  is the unique vector which represents this linear form in presence of the specified inner product, that is
$$d_pf(v)=\langle\nabla^{\langle .,.\rangle}f(p),v\rangle.$$

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to consider a function $f:\>{\cal O}\to{\mathbb R}$. Assume that the segment $[x,x+h]=:\sigma\subset{\cal O}$. We then are told that there is a $\theta\in(0,1)$ such that
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=\langle\nabla f(x+\theta h),h\rangle\ .\tag{1}$$
Now the definition of "differentiable" says that
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=\langle\nabla f(x),h\rangle+o\bigl(|h|\bigr)\qquad(h\to0)\ ,$$
so that we have the approximation $f(x+h)-f(x)\approx \langle\nabla f(x),h\rangle$ for small $|h|$. The relation $(1)$ gives an "exact equation", but involves an unknown $\theta\in(0,1)$. It says that the true increment $f(x+h)-f(x)$ is equal to the true derivative of $f$ at some point on $\sigma$, applied to the increment vector $h$ of the independent variable. This is the multivariate version of the MVT
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x+\theta h)\,h,\qquad0<\theta<1\ ,$$
from calculus 101.