# Gradient of $F(\mathbf{x}) = \|\mathbf{Ax}-\mathbf{b}\|_{2}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

So, I have a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$, $M\geq N$ with rank  $N$ and $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^M$. Unfortunately I'm a bit rusty on how to do multivariable calculus, so I would like to know how to calculate $\nabla F$ of

$$F(\mathbf{x})=\|\mathbf{Ax}-\mathbf{b}\|_{2}^2$$

I would furthermore also appreciate literature suggestions regarding sources where multivariable calculus is well explained, especially differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$F(x) = \Vert f(x) \Vert_2^2$$
where $f(x) = Ax - b$. Using the fact that $$\frac{d \Vert f(x) \Vert^2}{dx}  = 2\frac{df(x)}{dx}f(x)$$
and that 
$$\frac{df(x)}{dx} = A^T$$
we get
$$\frac{d \Vert f(x) \Vert^2}{dx}  = 2A^T(Ax-b)$$

## Why is $\frac{df(x)}{dx} = A^T$ ?

Since $f(x) = Ax - b$ is a vector then a derivative of a vector wrt a vector is defined as 
$$\frac{df(x)}{dx} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{df_1(x)}{dx_1} &  \frac{df_1(x)}{dx_2} & \ldots &  \frac{df_1(x)}{dx_n} \\ 
\vdots &  \vdots  & \ldots &  \vdots  \\ \frac{df_m(x)}{dx_1} &  \frac{df_m(x)}{dx_2} & \ldots &  \frac{df_m(x)}{dx_n} \end{bmatrix}^T$$
Since the derivative of $Ax-b$ is the same as that of $Ax$, let's consider $f(x) = Ax$, which looks like this 
$$f(x) = Ax = \begin{bmatrix} \sum_{j=1}^n A_{1j}x_j \\ \sum_{j=1}^n A_{2j}x_j \\ \vdots \\ \sum_{j=1}^n A_{mj}x_j \end{bmatrix}$$
Note that it is easy to see that 
$$\frac{df_i(x)}{dx_j} = A_{ij}$$
So we get $\frac{df(x)}{dx} = A^T$. 
Note that some references define $$\frac{df(x)}{dx} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{df_1(x)}{dx_1} &  \frac{df_1(x)}{dx_2} & \ldots &  \frac{df_1(x)}{dx_n} \\ 
\vdots &  \vdots  & \ldots &  \vdots  \\ \frac{df_m(x)}{dx_1} &  \frac{df_m(x)}{dx_2} & \ldots &  \frac{df_m(x)}{dx_n} \end{bmatrix}$$
which is laying the denominator vector as $x^T$, in that case you'll get that the derivative is $A$ and not its transpose.

Comment: Just something that strikes me now, why do we have to transpose A when calculating $\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}$ ?

Comment: @ChristianSinger I have edited the answer.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put into this. Thank you!

Comment: In fact, $\frac{d\;f(x)}{dx}$ isn't $A^T$, but $\nabla f(x)=A^T$ instead.

Comment: I was thinking about taking the jacobian of the expression but checking on wikipedia when they talk about vector by vector derivatives they say that there are two conventions for taking those derivatives. Apparently you are using the "denominator" layout, hence my confusion.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe that's just a question of notation.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Definitely not, it's a question of *representation*, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159730/dot-product-of-the-gradient-of-a-function/3160777#3160777.  So different inner products may result in different gradients for the same function.

Comment: but that's what I mean when I layout the denominator as $x$ or $x^T$ @MichaelHoppe

Answer (score 2):

Just apply product- and chain-rule:
$$\begin{align}D_x(\langle F(x),F(x)\rangle)(v)&=
2\langle D_x F(v),F(x)\rangle\\
&=2\langle Av,Ax-b\rangle\\
&=2\langle v,A^t(Ax-b)\rangle,
\end{align}$$
hence
$$\nabla F(x)=2A^t(Ax-b).$$

Answer (score 1):

We can always expand $F$. So, we have $F(\mathbf{x})=\|\mathbf{Ax}-\mathbf{b}\|_{2}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N\left(\sum_{j=1}^M (A_{i,j}x_j - b_j)\right)^2$. Now $\nabla F(x)_k = \sum_{i=1}^N 2A_{i,k}\sum_{j=1}^M(A_{i,j}x_j - b_j)$.