# Confusion about the gradient term in the directional derivatives of a vector

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, tangent-spaces

**Definition**: Let $f$ be a differentiable real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $\mathbf{v}_p$ be a tangent vector to it. Then the following number is the derivative of a function w.r.t. the tangent vector

$$ \mathbf{v}_p[f]=\frac{d}{dt}(f(\mathbf{p}+t \mathbf{v}))|t=0 $$
Further, there is this

Lemma: If $\mathbf{v}_p=(v_1,v_2,v_3)_p$ is a tangent vector to $\mathbb{R}^3$, then

$$\mathbf{v}_p[f]=\sum_i^3 v_i \frac{df}{dx_i} (\mathbf{p})$$

**Ques:** How does this gradient term $\frac{df}{dx_i} $ come into the picture? Is it that in the relation $f(\mathbf{p}+t \mathbf{v})$, we write the argument as $x(t)= \mathbf{p}+t \mathbf{v}$ and then apply the chain-rule in the definition?

*PS*: please keep the answer at the *level* of a physics undergraduate.

Comment: Maybe of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159730/dot-product-of-the-gradient-of-a-function/3160777#3160777

Comment: @MichaelHoppe The link that you provided needs some clarification of notation. What you wrote as $d_{\mathbf{p}} \mathit{f} \implies \frac{d \mathit{f}}{dx}|_{\mathbf{p}}$? I don't know what you mean by the term **linear form**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct: in order to find the directional derivative at $\mathbf{p}$ in the direction $\mathbf{v}$, consider a smooth curve $t\mapsto x(t)$ that at $t=0$ passes through $\mathbf{p}$ with velocity $\mathbf{v}$. Now compute the rate of change of $f$ along this curve at time $t=0$, i.e. compute $F'(0)$ where $F(t)=f(x(t))$. Use the chain rule and you are done.

Comment: Thanks! This really clears the confusion.

Comment: If this answers all of your question, you may accept it as an answer.

Comment: How should i accept it? is there a button to click?

Comment: There is a button on the left side below the upvote/downvote buttons.