# Gradient of a parametric surface, how can you express it in the space of the surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, parametric

For simplicity let's assume we are only working with $\mathbb{R}^3$.

We are given a parametric surface $s = <(X(u,v), Y(u,v), Z(u,v))>$ and a function $f: \mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
This implies that $f(s(u,v)) = F(u,v)$ for some function $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

The gradient of $F$ is merely $\nabla F = <\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}>$

This implies that:

$\nabla f = 
<\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial u} +
\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial u} +
\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial u}, 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial v} +
\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial v} +
\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial v}>$

This gives us the gradient expressed in the space of the domain, however, the gradient must also exist in the 3D space in which the surface is embedded. How do you obtain the gradient expressed in 3D?

(Also I am not entirely sure that my derivation is correct, so if it isn’t please let me know)

Comment: The gradient is a way to express the derivative of a function $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$, which is a linear form, by a vector, given an inner product, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159730/dot-product-of-the-gradient-of-a-function/3160777#3160777. As the derivative of $s$ isn't a linear form at all it may not be expressed by a vector.

Comment: I am confused by the reply, we are not taking the gradient of $s$ we are taking the gradient of $f(s)$ which is a scalar valued function of 2 variables and must necessarily have a well defined gradient as long as all the components are continuous.

Comment: You said you started with a function $f$ on all of $\Bbb  R^3$. So what is the problem?

Comment: The reply of @MichaelHoppe says `As the derivative of s isn't a linear form at all it may not be expressed by a vector`

However I am looking at the derivative of $f(s)$ which should be expressable as a vector.

Comment: The gradient of what *must also exist in the 3D space*?

Comment: The gragient of $f(s)$. Given a point in the surface of $s$ and the scalar function $f$, there must be a vector $v$ such that if $s$ is locally approximated by a plane $p$ that contains $v$ and $f$ is locally approximated by $h \approx f$ on the epsilon neighbourhoud around $p$,  $v$ is the direction of greatest change on $h$.

In other words, if $s$ is manifold, then it can be locally approximated by a plane. That plane can be evaluated by an approximation of $f$ that is adapted to planes. A gradient vector objectively exists in that configuration.

Comment: So there must be a gradient vector in 3D that tells you, locally, the direction of greatest change of $f$ along the surface $s$. 

Put in different terms, you should be able to do gradient descent on the surface of a manifold surface that has a continuous scalar function defined everywhere on its surface.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe In case you are interested: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_gradient

That's the answer