# Does approaching the vector that defines the direction sequentially preserve the directional derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

I'm working on some admissible cones to minimize some differentiable scalar function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. And I wondered if such a statement would be true. It would definitely make my life easier.
$$\frac{f(x + t_{k}h_{k})-f(x)}{t_{k}} \rightarrow \nabla_{h}f(x) $$ for some sequence of vectors $h_{k} \rightarrow h$ and some sequence of strictly positive reals $t_{k} \rightarrow 0$

Comment: I have a feeling that it should be true for differentiable functions, but it's definitely not true for functions which aren't differentiable.

Comment: It seems that you're mixing up the derivative $d_xf(h)$ -- the limit you describe -- with the gradient of $f$, see   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159730/dot-product-of-the-gradient-of-a-function/3160777#3160777

Comment: Definitely not, the directional derivative $\nabla_{h}f:=\langle \nabla f \, , h \rangle $

Comment: Can't you simply choose $h_k = h$? You have $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t} = \nabla f(x) \cdot h$.

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of the problem I'm working on, namely K-admissible cones $A_{K}(x)$ where $h \in A_{K}(x)$ iff there exista sequences as listed above such that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ $x+t_{k}h_{k} \in K$