# What is $f'(x)$ if $f(x)=\langle x,x\rangle$ for $x \in \mathbb R^n$?

Tags: calculus

What is $f'(x)$ if $f(x)=\langle x,x\rangle$ for $x \in \mathbb R^n$?

How $x=(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n$?

I did $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2$ then $f'(x)=[\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2]' =2\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i $, is this right?

Comment: $f'(x)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R^{n}$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: so my try is wrong?

Comment: You should always first figure out what all the symbols mean that you use. Here we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$ We relate a scalar to any point in an n-dimensional space. $f'$ measures a change. In which direction? What does $f'$ stand for in n dimensions? You could either pick a coordinate direction, but that would have been the partial derivative, or a general direction, a generic linear combination of all directions, i.e. all partial derivatives. Short: what is $f'$?

Comment: Hint: compute $f(x+h) - f(x)$ and keep only the linear terms in $h$.

Comment: See  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159730/dot-product-of-the-gradient-of-a-function/3160777#3160777 In our case $$d_pf(v)=2\langle p,v\rangle.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since your function accepts $n$-dimensional inputs, you can compute the gradient, or partial derivatives. As you wrote, you have $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2$, so that

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2\right)= \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(x_j^2\right)=2x_i$$

Thus, the gradient is

$$\nabla f(x)=2x.$$