# $\mathrm{grad}\ f|_p$ is normal to the level set of $f$ through $p$ if $p$ is a regular point of a function $f$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Please allow me to write with reference to John Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. Thank you.

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and let $f$ be a smooth function on $M$ with a regular point $p$. I'd like to show that $\mathrm{grad}\ f|_p$ is normal to the level set of $f$ through $p$. Below is what I have tried so far:

> Let $f(p)=c$. If I understand correctly,  $f^{-1}(c)$ is the level set of $f$ through $p$. Thus, I will have to show that for each $x\in f^{-1}(c)$ and for each $u\in T_x M$,
> $$\langle u,\mathrm{grad}\ f|_p\rangle_g=0.\tag{1}$$
> From now on, I will always denote local coordinates by $(x^i)$, meaning that I will write
> $$u=u^k\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}|_x\tag{2}$$
> and
> $$\mathrm{grad}\ f|_p=g^{ij}(p)\frac{\partial\hat{f}}{\partial x^i}(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}|_p\tag{3}$$
> with $\hat{f}$ denoting the coordinate representation of $f$ in $(x^i)$. Plugging (2) and (3) into (1), I get
> $$\langle u,\mathrm{grad}\ f|_p\rangle_g=u^k g^{ij}(p)\frac{\partial\hat{f}}{\partial x^i}(p)\langle\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}|_x,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}|_p\rangle_g,$$
> which seems to lead me nowhere. I'm aware that I haven't appealed to the definition of a regular point, but it seems to make no difference after I try it. What I will get is merely a surjective map $df_p$, which can be locally expressed as
> $$df_p=\frac{\partial\hat{f}}{\partial x^i}(p)dx^i|_p.\tag{4}$$
> What should I do next? Thank you.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1977/why-is-the-gradient-normal for an exhaustive discussion.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159730/dot-product-of-the-gradient-of-a-function/3160777#3160777

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question asks you to show

> If $p$ is a regular point of $f$, then $\mathrm{grad}f|_p$ is orthogonal to $\Sigma$, the level set of $f$ through $p$.

Watch out, "$\mathrm{grad}f|_p$ is orthogonal to $\Sigma$, the level set through $p$" does not mean, as you seem to believe, the following:

> $\forall x \in \Sigma, \forall u \in T_x\Sigma,\quad \langle \mathrm{grad}f|_p,u\rangle = 0$.

There are two reasons why this does not even make sense:

- First, while $p$ is by assumption a regular point of $f$ and therefore $\Sigma$ is a submanifold in a neighbourhood of $p$, there is no reason for $\Sigma$ to be regular away from $p$, and $T_x\Sigma$ does not even make sense there.
- Second, $\mathrm{grad}f|_p$ is a vector tangent at $p$, so it can only be compared to other vectors tangent at $p$.
  If $u$ is tangent at any other point than $p$, its scalar product with $\mathrm{grad}f|_p$ has no meaning.
  For instance, you wrote
  $$
  \left\langle\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\right|_x,\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right|_p\right\rangle_g
  $$
  which makes absolutely no sense at all.
  It is a good and important exercise to convince yourself about that precise point.

What it really means is:

> $\forall u \in T_p\Sigma, \quad \langle \mathrm{grad}f|_p,u\rangle = 0$.

Below is a proof of this correct interpretation of the question.

---

You do not need to use any computation, only the definition of the gradient of a function and the characterisation of tangent vectors as derivatives of curves.

Let $p\in M$ be a regular point for $f\colon (M,g)\to \Bbb R$, and let $\Sigma = f^{-1}(f(p))$ be the level set through $p$.
Since $p\in \Sigma$ is a regular point, $\Sigma$ is a smooth hypersurface in a neighbourhood of $p$.
Let $u\in T_p\Sigma$ be a tangent vector, and $\gamma\colon (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to \Sigma$ a smooth curve such that $\gamma(0) = p$, $\gamma'(0) = u$.
Then
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad} \newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}
\langle \grad\! f|_p,u\rangle = \d_pf(u) = \left.\frac{\d \left(f\circ\gamma(t)\right)} {\d t}\right|_{t=0}.
$$
Since $\gamma$ has range in $\Sigma$ which is by definition the level set through $p$, $f\circ \gamma\colon (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \to \Bbb R$ is constant, equal to $f(p) \in \Bbb R$.
Consequently, one has $\langle \grad\! f|_p,u\rangle = 0$.
This being true for any $u\in T_p\Sigma$, one concludes that $\grad f|_p \perp T_p\Sigma$.

Comment: Thank you, but I have two questions. First, what's the point in "Let $p\in \Sigma_c$ be a regular point, so that $\Sigma_c$ is a smooth hypersurface in a neighbourhood of $p$."? The letter $p$ is already used to denote the given regular point, isn't it? Second, if we want to prove $\mathrm{grad}\ f|_p$ is normal to $\Sigma_c$, then it will be necessary to pick an arbitrary point $x$ from $\Sigma_c$ and consider $T_x\Sigma_c$, right? Why didn't you do that? Thank you.

Comment: @Wombat The point is to have a self contained question, so that a reader won't have to go back to your question in order to understand what is $p$ in the proof. // For a vector $v\in T_pM$ to be orthogonal to a hypersurface $\Sigma$ passing through $p$ **precisely** means $v \perp T_p\Sigma$. The point $p$ is the one and only point that makes sense since one cannot compare a tangent vector at $p$ with something that belongs to another tangent space. How would you even define orthogonality between $\mathrm{grad}f|_p$ and $u \in T_qM$ with $q \neq p$?

Comment: (self contained answer*)

Comment: Sorry, I still can't get it. Why didn't you cope with a point in $\Sigma_c$ that may NOT be a regular point? I mean, aren't you worried about those critical points? Is any property there to ensure that each point in $\Sigma_c$ is a regular point of $f$?

Comment: @Wombat Your question explicitly asks for regular points, isn't it? Maybe the new formulation is less ambiguous.

Comment: Sure, $p$ is a regular point, but $\Sigma_c$ may not be entirely made up of regular points. The level set of $f$ through $p$ can be visually seen as a surface, and I'm not that sure about the idea that each point of this surface is a regular point. You can check again the original statement of my question, and I didn't seem to indicate your understanding of the question.

Comment: @Wombat I never said that $\Sigma$ was regular everywhere. I said it was regular in a neighbourhood of $p$. This is due to the assumption that $p$ is a regular point of $f$, and is shown at the very begining of the vast majority of any lecture / textbook section on submanifolds.
\\
The gradient $\mathrm{grad}f|_p$ is a vector defined only at $p$. There is absolutely no meaning in looking at other points were $\Sigma$ might not be regular.

Comment: @Wombat I added an intro explaining why what you wanted to show makes no sense, and what is really meant by the question.

Comment: I haven't fully digested your proof, but you just pointed out one critical mistake I made. Yes, you are right: $\mathrm{grad}\ f|_p$ is a tangent vector at $p$.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? The exercise does assume that $p$ is a regular point, but what if it is not? Does the result still hold? I asked this because some posts do not involve the regular-point assumption: they simply assume the gradient is nowhere zero. Is it equivalent to our regular-point assumption? Thank you.

Comment: @Wombat $p$ is a regular point $\iff \mathrm{d}_pf \neq 0 \iff \mathrm{grad}f|_p \neq 0$. As for your question: if $p$ is not regular, then $\mathrm{grad}f|_p = 0$ is orthogonal to whatever you want. Note that the level set needs not be regular around $p$ to that it may fail to have a tangent space.

Comment: Really? I thought regular points are defined as points where the differential is surjective...at least, the text told me so.

Comment: @Wombat In case of a linear function with range in $\Bbb R$, surjectivity is equivalent to being nonzero. Note that the gradient only makes sense for functions taking real values.

Comment: Thank you. You are probably an angel in disguise.